# Return only one row based on search

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Query

```
select 
a.id,
a.ba,
b.status,
b.custid
from balist as a
inner join customer as b
on a.ba = b.ba
```

I have a table "balist" that has a list of (ba) and i inner join table "customer" on (ba) and right now by output is like the following

| id | ba | status | custid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ba-1234455 | A | 123-321-123-321a |
| 2 | ba-1234455 | I | 123-321-123-321a |
| 3 | ba-1234457 | A | 123-321-123-321b |
| 4 | ba-1234458 | A | 123-321-123-321c |
| 5 | ba-1234459 | I | 123-321-123-321d |

and I want to return all A and I status but remove the row that has status I that also have a A status. Like the following.

I have a table customer like the following

| id | ba | status | custid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ba-1234455 | A | 123-321-123-321a |
| 3 | ba-1234457 | A | 123-321-123-321b |
| 4 | ba-1234458 | A | 123-321-123-321c |
| 5 | ba-1234459 | I | 123-321-123-321d |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `row_number()` to filter your resulting rows eg

```sql
SELECT
    id,ba,status,custid
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.ba,
        b.status,
        b.custid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY a.ba
             ORDER BY b.status ASC
        ) as rn
    FROM
        balist as a
    INNER JOIN 
        customer as b ON a.ba = b.ba
)
WHERE rn=1
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: where is "ba." being set?  getting error ""Unrecognized name: ba.  ..... should i change "ba." to  "c."

Comment: @MichaelPeterson I only assumed you had a column named `ba` in your `balist` table and provided the example query as such. If you update your question to share your existing query I may update the answer to  better match your query and existing schema.

Comment: updated question with query

Comment: @MichaelPeterson I've updated the answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: worked thanks again